# Using MongoDB $pull to delete documents within an Array

Tags: mongodb, pull

I have a collection in MongoDB, which is like following:

```
{
    "_id" : "5327010328645530500",
    "members" : [
        {
            "participationCoeff" : 1,
            "tweetID" : "5327010328645530500"
        },
        {
            "participationCoeff" : 1,
            "tweetID" : "2820402625046999289"
        },
        {
            "participationCoeff" : 0.6666666666666666,
            "tweetID" : "6122060484520699114"
        },
        {
            "participationCoeff" : 1,
            "tweetID" : "4656669980325872747"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2646953848367646922",
    "members" : [
        {
            "participationCoeff" : 1,
            "tweetID" : "2646953848367646922"
        },
        {
            "participationCoeff" : 0.75,
            "tweetID" : "7750833069621794130"
        },
        {
            "participationCoeff" : 0.5,
            "tweetID" : "6271782334664128453"
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, collection have clusters, where a cluster has an `_id` field and a `members` field. Members field is an array of documents, having following format.

```
{
            "participationCoeff" : 1,
            "tweetID" : "5327010328645530500"
        }
```

Now, from time to time, I have to delete these sub-documents in members attribute of cluster document, by matching tweetID.

However, I'm not able to find a query to achieve this effect. Basically, a tweetID will participate in many clusters, and hence will appear in multiple sub-documents of 'members' attribute of various clusters. I want to supply a bulk $pull operation, where I can remove all the sub-documents in all the clusters (i.e. their members attribute) which match on a particular tweetID.

Some help and intuition will be really helpful.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That's exactly what the `$pull` operator does, so in the shell you could use an `update` like:

```js
db.clusters.update({}, 
    {$pull: {members: {tweetID: '5327010328645530500'}}}, 
    {multi: true})
```

Set the `multi` option so that every document is updated, not just the first one.

Comment: getting following error.

`Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array`

Comment: @VaidAbhishek That means that you have some docs in the collection where `members` isn't an array.

Comment: I don't think that is the case with my collection. members will be a strictly array type attribute of cluster.

Is there any way of doing this using aggregation!

Comment: @VaidAbhishek Are you sure?  Even if `members` is `null` in a doc that would cause this error as that's not an array.

Comment: I don't think that is the case :-(

Answer (score 10):

This will delete `multiple tweets` in a single query just pass an array to `$in`:-

```
db.clusters.update({}, 
{$pull: {members: {$in: [ {tweetID: '5327010328645530500'},{"tweetID" : "2820402625046999289"} ] } } }, 
{multi: true});
```

The above method doesnt work in mongoose 
so for mongoose do:-

```
 db.clusters.update({}, 
{$pull: {members:[ {tweetID: '5327010328645530500'},{"tweetID" : "2820402625046999289"} ]  } });
```

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime the update method is deprecated. Therefore one possible up-to-date solution to this would be using the updateMany method instead.

```
db.clusters.updateMany({}, 
    {$pull: {members: {tweetID: '5327010328645530500'}}})
```

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: Used in `"mongoose": "^5.12.13"`.

As for today June 22nd, 2021, you can use `$in` and `$pull` mongodb operators to remove items from an array of documents :

**Parent Document :**

```
{
    "name": "June Grocery",
    "description": "Remember to pick Ephraim's favorit milk",
    "createdDate": "2021-06-09T20:17:29.029Z",
    "_id": "60c5f64f0041190ad312b419",
    "items": [],
    "budget": 1500,
    "owner": "60a97ea7c4d629866c1d99d1",
}
```

**Documents in Items array :**

```
{
    "category": "Fruits",
    "bought": false,
    "id": "60ada26be8bdbf195887acc1",
    "name": "Kiwi",
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1
},
{
    "category": "Toiletry",
    "bought": false,
    "id": "60b92dd67ae0934c8dfce126",
    "name": "Toilet Paper",
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1
},
{
    "category": "Toiletry",
    "bought": false,
    "id": "60b92fe97ae0934c8dfce127",
    "name": "Toothpaste",
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1
},
{
    "category": "Toiletry",
    "bought": false,
    "id": "60b92ffb7ae0934c8dfce128",
    "name": "Mouthwash",
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1
},
{
    "category": "Toiletry",
    "bought": false,
    "id": "60b931fa7ae0934c8dfce12d",
    "name": "Body Soap",
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1
},
{
    "category": "Fruit",
    "bought": false,
    "id": "60b9300c7ae0934c8dfce129",
    "name": "Banana",
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1
},
{
    "category": "Vegetable",
    "bought": false,
    "id": "60b930347ae0934c8dfce12a",
    "name": "Sombe",
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1
},
```

**Query :**

```
MyModel.updateMany(
    { _id: yourDocumentId },
    { $pull: { items: { id: { $in: itemIds } } } },
    { multi: true }
);
```

**Note**: ItemIds is an array of `ObjectId`.
See below :

```
[
  '60ada26be8bdbf195887acc1',
  '60b930347ae0934c8dfce12a',
  '60b9300c7ae0934c8dfce129'
]
```