# $pull not removing document from an Array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a MongoDB document that looks like this:

```
"_id": ObjectID(48kf4kblahblahblah),
"name": "A Person's Name",
"username":  "apersonsemail@mail.com",
"password":  "a hashed password",
"formulas":  [
               {
                 "f_id": ObjectID(4k8s9blahblahblah),
                 "name": "A Name",
                 "description": "A description",
                 "ingredients": [{object}, {object}]
               }
             ]
}
```

I'm trying to query for a document based on `_id` and then remove the sub-document from the `formulas` array based on an item's `f_id` value using `$pull`.

However, it's not updating anything.

This is taking part in an Express/Node application, and my code looks like this:

```
router.delete('/formula-list/:index', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db.collection('users');
  var index = req.params.index;
  db.updateOne({"_id": new ObjectID(req.user.id)}, { $pull: {"formulas": {"f_id": index}} }, function(err, r){
             assert.equal(null, err);
             assert.equal(1, r.modifiedCount);
             req.db.close();
           });
  res.end();
});
```

And I get `Assertion Error: 1 == 0`

I've consoled `req.params.index` and I get the value

```
59683b480986823e10f39fba
```

And if I console the `r` object the `matchedCount` is 1, so I know it's finding the document as well.  It's just not doing anything with it.

My questions seems [very similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121758/using-mongodb-pull-to-delete-documents-within-an-array), with the exception that I'm not looking to delete multiple items, but I don't see how this would affect the results of my query.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this mongoose or the core node driver? If it's the latter you need to cast to `ObjectId`, otherwise things do not match and nothing gets done. I'm guessing it's "core" since you use `ObjectId` on the primary `_id`. So you need to change the `$pull` as well `{ $pull: { "formulas": { "f_id": ObjectID(index) } } }`

Comment: @NeilLunn - Yes, this was it.  If you put this as an answer I'll mark it complete.

Comment: I was trying remove array index with pull as using php.. but it was not removed... cuz of  condition element was integer so i cast int and it removed