# MongoDB - Update objects remove item in send array in object (nested updating)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

this is my mongodb object

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4faaba123412d654fe83hg876"),
    "user_id" : 123456,
    "posters" : [ 123456,1111,456789,3333]
}
```

i want to add an item to posters array , or remove one how could i do it ?

its nested updating.

i saw some question around stackoverflow , but i didnt found any answer how to remove object from the array , lets say 3333 there .

so the result will be :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4faaba123412d654fe83hg876"),
    "user_id" : 123456,
    "posters" : [ 123456,1111,456789]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MongoDB $pull to delete documents within an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121758/using-mongodb-pull-to-delete-documents-within-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

```
db.collection.update(
    { posters: "3333" },
    { $pull: { posters: "3333" } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: Please do not answer direct dups, let those be closed, that makes users do their homework first rather than posting everything they want :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use $push to add something into an array :

```
db.collection.update(
{ $push:
    {
        "posters" : "0000"
    }
}
)
```

Use $pull to remove something from an array:

```
db.collection.update(
{ $pull:
    {
        "posters" : "3333"
    }
}, True
)
```