# MongoDB delete embedded documents through array of Ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a `Node.js` application that is using a `MongoDB` database with [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/). I've been stuck in this thing and didn't come up with the right query.

**Problem:**

There is a collection named `chats` which contain embedded documents `(rooms)` as an array of objects. I want to delete these embedded documents `(rooms)` through `Ids` which are in the array.

```
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6138e2b55c175846ec1e38c5)",
    "type": "bot",
    "rooms": [
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId(6138e2b55c145846ec1e38c5)",
        "genre": "action"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId(6138e2b545c145846ec1e38c5)",
        "genre": "adventure"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6138e2b55c1765846ec1e38c5)",
    "type": "person",
    "rooms": [
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId(6138e2565c145846ec1e38c5)",
        "genre": "food"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId(6138e2b5645c145846ec1e38c5)",
        "genre": "sport"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6138e2b55c1765846ec1e38c5)",
    "type": "duo",
    "rooms": [
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId(6138e21c145846ec1e38c5)",
        "genre": "travel"
      },
      {
        "_id": "ObjectId(6138e35645c145846ec1e38c5)",
        "genre": "news"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am converting my array of `ids` into MongoDB `ObjectId` so I can use these ids as match criteria.

```
const idsRoom = [
  '6138e21c145846ec1e38c5',
  '6138e2565c145846ec1e38c5',
  '6138e2b545c145846ec1e38c5',
];

const objectIdArray = idsRoom.map((s) => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(s));
```

and using this query for the chat collection. But it is deleting the whole document and I only want to delete the `rooms` embedded document because the ids array is only for the embedded documents.

```
Chat.deleteMany({ 'rooms._id': objectIdArray }, function (err) {
  console.log('Delete successfully')
})
```

I really appreciate your help on this issue.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121758/using-mongodb-pull-to-delete-documents-within-an-array) looks very similar, you dotn need to delete, you want to update, and change the array, delete refers only to documents not embeded documents

Comment: @Takis_ But how can we delete without knowing the `parent Id` we only have Ids for the embedded documents.

Comment: oh ok its not the same completly,you want to search with a path, i think you need to make an index on that rooms._id field to be fast, if you will search by it (multikey index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator in a `update` query like this:

This query look for documents where exists the `_id` into `rooms` array and use `$pull` to remove the object from the array.

```
yourModel.updateMany({
  "rooms._id": {
    "$in": [
      "6138e21c145846ec1e38c5",
      "6138e2565c145846ec1e38c5",
      "6138e2b545c145846ec1e38c5"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "rooms": {
      "_id": {
        "$in": [
          "6138e21c145846ec1e38c5",
          "6138e2565c145846ec1e38c5",
          "6138e2b545c145846ec1e38c5"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/loBRhpNjdWF).

Also you can run your query without the `query` parameter (in [update queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) the first object is the `query`) [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xkxKhlwe7KN) and result is the same. But is better to indicate mongo the documents using this first object.